# Running unit tests with Jenkins and Ant

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, ant, jenkins

I have just started using Jenkins for a small project and as part of that, would like the unit tests to be run every time it builds.

I understand that you need to put a test target in your build file and specify this target in the job configuration, but I am using the build file generated by NetBeans, therefore if I modify it I assume it will just get overwritten.

My project is an enterprise application which is made of a single `jar`. The build script I am using is for the enterprise application, not the `jar`, so that an `ear` file is produced which I can then deploy to an application server.

Currently the build passes and produces and `ear` file which I can deploy and works, but nowhere in the console output does it show that it is running the tests.

The unit tests are in the `jar` project, so how can I get Jenkins to run the unit tests when it builds the `ear` file?

Answer (score 0):

Question can be bit more clear - When your tests are executed ?

If your build runs the unit tests but not shown in the console, you should find a way to display it in console.
Like in Unix, executable run_qa_test > capture_results.txt - will capture all the results in the txt file and not display in console.
This can be modified as run_qa_test | tee capture_results.txt - This will display the output in console and record in txt file as well.

Or ,if you build produces ear file and if your tests in jar is not executed as part of the build job, you can create a new job as downstream of the build job and run those tests finally.
Or if needed to run only as part of the same build job you need to modify the build process